# How to partition a set with a condition on subsets?

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics

I want to partition a set of $n$ elements into $k$ subsets with a condition
For example:
partitioning this set {1,...,5} into 3 subsets with this condition: if $|i-j|<d$ then $i$ can't be with $j$ in the same subset, with $i,j\in \{1,...,5\}$ and $d\in \mathbb{N}$.
For $d=2$ we have $7$ partition:

$\{\{1\}\{2,4\}\{3,5\}\}$, $\{\{1,3\}\{2,4\}\{5\}\}$, $\{\{1,3\}\{2,5\}\{4\}\}$, $\{\{1,4\}\{2,5\}\{3\}\}$

$\{\{1,4\}\{2\}\{3,5\}\}$, $\{\{1,5\}\{2,4\}\{3\}\}$,$\{\{1,3,5\}\{2\}\{4\}\}$, 
$\{\{1,3\}\{2,4\}\{5\}\}$

Thank You.

Comment: I don't see why your condition can always be satisfied.  For instance, if you want to break $\{ 1 \ldots 10 \}$ into $k = 3$ subsets such that if $|i - j| < 3$ then $i$ cannot be in the same subset as $j$.

Comment: David G. Stork  In your case we have 0 ways to partition a set of 10 elements into 3 subsets with this condition $|i-j|<3$, its like Stirling numbers of second kind if we have  $k>n$ then we have 0 ways to partition the set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A brute force approach (not to be used with large lists):

```
partitionsF[lst_, k_, cond_] := Module[{s1 = Subsets[lst, {1, Infinity}], s2,
   sF1 = (And @@ (! cond @@ # & /@ Subsets[#, {2}])) &, 
   sF2 = And[ Union @@ # == lst, ## & @@ (Intersection@@# == {} & /@ Subsets[#, {2}])] &}, 
  s2 = Subsets[Pick[s1, sF1 /@ s1], {k}];
  Pick[s2, sF2 /@ s2]]
```

Examples

```
partitionsF[Range[5], 3, Abs[# - #2] < 2 &]
```

> {{{1}, {2, 4}, {3, 5}}, {{2}, {4}, {1, 3, 5}}, {{2}, {1, 4}, {3, 5}},
>         {{3}, {1, 4}, {2, 5}}, {{3}, {1, 5}, {2, 4}}, {{4}, {1, 3}, {2, 5}}, 
>         {{5}, {1, 3}, {2, 4}}}

```
partitionsF[Range[5], 3, Abs[# - #2] < 3 &]
```

> {{{3}, {1, 4}, {2, 5}}}

```
partitionsF[Range[5], 2, Abs[# - #2] < 2 &]
```

> {{{2, 4}, {1, 3, 5}}}

```
partitionsF[Range[5], 2, Abs[# - #2] < 3 &]
```

> {}

Comment: kglr Thank you for your answer but the condition is the  opposite if $i$ and  $j$ don't verify the condition they cannot be in the same subset, for  example `partitionsF[Range[5], 3, Max@#- Min@# < 2 &]` that mean partition of $\{1,...,5\}$ into 3 subsets with $|i-j|<2$ and it's the same example I gave in the statement and I found 7 ways to partition this set but in your answer you find 3 ways that i have not found.

Comment: @OAMAZF, oops:) Updated with a fix.

Comment: kglr Thank You very much for you answer :) .

Answer (score 4):

**Update**
My original answer was fun but not efficient.

```
sfunc[r_, d_, k_] := Module[{rng, s, df, se, g, fp, su, c, ans},
  rng = Range[r];
  s = Rest@Subsets[rng];
  df[x_?(Length@# == 1 &)] := Infinity;
  df[x_] := Min[Differences@x];
  se = Select[s, df[#] >= d &];
  g = RelationGraph[Intersection[#1, #2] == {} &, se];
  c = FindClique[g, {k}, All]
  ]
```

Now testing (the first column is d, the second column k, the third column is number of partitons):

```
disp[n_] := 
 Grid[{#1, #2, 
     OpenerView[{Length[#3], #3}]} & @@@ ({##, sfunc[n, ##]} & @@@ 
     Tuples[Range[2, n - 1], 2]), Frame -> All]
```

[image]

[image]

** Original Answer**

Just for fun:

```
r = Range[5];
s = Rest@Subsets[r];
df[x_?(Length@# == 1 &)] := Infinity;
df[x_] := Min[Differences@x];
se = Select[s, df[#] >= 2 &];
g = RelationGraph[Intersection[#1, #2] == {} &, se];
fp[u_, v_] := DeleteCases[FindPath[g, u, v, {2}, All], {{_}, {_}, {_}}]
su = Subsets[VertexList[g], {2}];
c = Catenate[fp @@@ su];
ans = Union[Sort /@ Pick[c, Sort[Flatten[#]] == r & /@ c]]
```

yields:

```
{{{1}, {2, 4}, {3, 5}}, {{2}, {4}, {1, 3, 5}}, {{2}, {1, 4}, {3, 
   5}}, {{3}, {1, 4}, {2, 5}}, {{3}, {1, 5}, {2, 4}}, {{4}, {1, 
   3}, {2, 5}}, {{5}, {1, 3}, {2, 4}}}
```

You could adjust  to obtain desired ordering,e.g.

```
SortBy[#, Min[#] &] & /@ ans
```

yields:

```
{{{1}, {2, 4}, {3, 5}}, {{1, 3, 5}, {2}, {4}}, {{1, 4}, {2}, {3, 
   5}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3}}, {{1, 5}, {2, 4}, {3}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 
   5}, {4}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}, {5}}}
```

Comment: This is super nice, +1. I was also looking for a solution with the function `FindClique`, but I used it with the pairs of elements in `r` satisfying the condition. Reconstructing all the complete subgraphs and taking the null intersections between them became messy after that. I find your idea of constructing a graph where each node is a complete graph very nice.

Comment: @Xavier thank you...perhaps you will find a better way...I am always learning from this site :)

Answer (score 3):

This should do

```
ConditionalPartition[list_, k_, cond_] := Module[{y},
  y = Table[{}, {k}];
  Do[Do[
    If[y[[j]] == {} || (AllTrue[y[[j]], cond[#, list[[i]]] &] && Quiet[y[[j + 1]] =!= {}]),
      AppendTo[y[[j]], list[[i]]];
      Break[]]
    , {j, k}], {i, Length@list}];
  If[Sort[list] == Sort@Flatten[y, 1], y, $Failed]
]
```

*list* is the set, *k* the amount of subsets and *cond* a function that evaluates to `True` if both arguments may appear together in one subset.

The function hoever is dependent on the ordering of *list* and provides only one solution.

```
ConditionalPartition[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 3, ! Abs[# - #2] < 2 &]
(* {{1, 3, 5}, {2}, {4}} *)
ConditionalPartition[{1, 5, 4, 2, 3}, 3, ! Abs[# - #2] < 2 &]
(* {{1, 4}, {5, 3}, {2}} *)
```